# Received SMS not being shown when my activity is in foreground. But, when I reopen the app, it gets displayed

Tags: android, sms, receiver

I have used a handler that runs every 1000 milliseconds in my activity but nothing has changed.
When I use the same handler in my **SMSReceiver** broadcast receiver class, the activity and its adapter are facing a null pointer problem.

```
public void update(){

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            convListActivity.getConvListData2();
            convListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

And then, I have called this method in `onReceive` method of my broadcast receiver class.

> Null pointer exception

is being shown at these lines:

```
convListActivity.getConvListData2();
convListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

`convListActivity` and `convListAdapter` are the activity and its adapter classes.